# Reduce video call quality in messaging apps while using mobile data

Tags: mobile-data, data-connection, video-calling

I see that most of the messaging apps that support video calls set the video quality automatically. WhatsApp, imo, Skype are the most famous examples.

That is bad actually... I have a high-speed data connection. So the apps increase video quality to the best level. What is the result? Some hundred megabytes of data transfer during some 10 minutes and that means more money to pay. I don't want that. I prefer medium quality.

What is the solution then? Any tweaks for the apps? Any other alternative messaging app?

Comment: Do you have a device with root access ? ... This could be important because having root access allows system modification's such as image quality, streaming quality etc.. Their could be a simple way to restrict your network bandwidth therefore lowering data usage and tricking the app into using a lower quality.  ... P.S their is some NON-ROOT applications that could possibly help by tricking the app into using a different network for calls, like Privacy Blocker, this will allow you to modify the network type that the application see's, an example would be having your device connected to WI-FI

Comment: continued...    however the application will recognise the connection as 3G, this could significantly reduce data usage for some applications.

Comment: I can not find "privacy blocker" in play. Maybe that is available in some countries.

Comment: It's a application that uses smali inspection to identity privacy information, this means that it has to reverse engineer the app and therefore violates the play terms, you'll still find it on Google however.